# Mysql inserting a row in a table with a specific sequence

Tags: php, android, mysql

I m trying to add rows into Database using PHP in webhosting site. 000webhost.com and converting it into JSON later accessed by android app but every time i add a row it ads up randomly into the table. I need a specific query or code that puts the data exactly after the last inserted row.. in MYSQL.

```
$sql="select * from homepage_newsfeed;";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$response = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
array_push($response, array("subject"=>$row[0],"description"=>$row[1]));
}
echo json_encode(array("data"=>$response));
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you want data in a particular order in a query, then you need to use an `order by` clause.

Comment: Thnx for the information it really helped me out..!! thnx again.